# Faild to build spring boot jar on different environments

Tags: java, spring

community!

Here's my situation. I have spring boot application. It is built using maven and packaged in jar file. The problem is when I build it on my development PC and ran everything works well. If I ran this jar file on our staging environment, which is linux, it also runs well. But if I build it ON staging environment(this is done by our Jenkins server, of course) it fails during launch time with exception:

> 2016-11-28 16:11:47.777  WARN 9443 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   2016-11-28 16:11:47.781  INFO 9443 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
>   2016-11-28 16:11:47.804  WARN 9443 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
>   2016-11-28 16:11:47.943 ERROR 9443 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field passwordEncoder in no.sykling.rest.AuthenticationController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' in your configuration.

Here's how my spring security configuration looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

@Autowired private Environment environment;
@Autowired private UserService userService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder managerBuilder) throws Exception {
    managerBuilder.userDetailsService(userService);
    managerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return provider;
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/partials/**", "index.html");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/v1/authenticate/login", "/v1/authenticate/logout", "/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
        .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .csrf().disable();
}

private AuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler() {
    return ((request, response, authentication) -> response.sendRedirect("/dashboard"));
}

private AuthenticationFailureHandler loginFailureHandler() {
    return ((request, response, exception) -> response.sendRedirect("/"));
}

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
}
```

}

BCryptPasswordEncoder bean is clearly defined and when I run application in debugger it seems autowired correctly. But once application is built on our linux machine it fails to start.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone experienced similar situation...

Bean definition was **passwordEncoder**, however I tried to wire it up as **encoder**. Once I specified full name, like passwordEncoder that worked as expected.

Not sure why autowiring worked for my IDE though.